# WebdriverIO Appium - Not able to sendKeys or enter value in the input field

Tags: android, appium, ui-automation, webdriver-io, appium-android

Using Appium to automate a website on Android chrome browser. After visiting the website, gets a pop up to enter username and password. Tried all combinations, but unable to switch and type or setValue in the username and password field.

It is Native pop up, and can see nested Framelayout's, tried switchFrame() as well, didn't help.

Below is the screenshot of the app and the element tree

Tried all combinations: resource-id, Xpath, id etc

Please can someone help with this?

Using: WebdriverIO, Appium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a native pop-up, I'm thinking you might need to switch to another context. And then switch back once done with the pop-up.

I don't know which language you're writing in, but here's how to do it in Java:

```
// Switch to pop-up:
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
//Switch back:
driver.context("WEBVIEW");
```

Could you give that a try?

Comment: Thanks @valies it worked, the only thing that was missing was, I needed to add wait for driver to switch context and input the values.

Comment: I am able to switch context and enter the values, but when I check the context of the page after the pop-up it still shows "NATIVE_APP", and the driver is not able to click on any other elements. Please can you suggest what might be happening?